# Item in UIStackView not appearing

Tags: ios, swift, uistackview

https://spin.atomicobject.com/2017/02/20/uistackview-stacking-child-views/

I am following along this tutorial to get views stacking on top of each other and using their intrinsic content size. However when I apply the Content Hugging Priority to the signOffSignatureContainer, the view disappears, and the commentsContainer takes up the full screen.

```
class AssessmentSignOffViewController: UIViewController, SignatureDrawingViewControllerDelegate {


    private var signOffCommentsLabel: UILabel!
    private var signOffCommentsTextView: UITextView!
    private var signatureVCContainer: UIView!
    private var signatureLabel: UILabel!

    private var signatureViewController = SignatureDrawingViewController()

    lazy var signOffSignatureContainer: UIView = { [unowned self] in
        var signOffSignatureContainer = UIView()

        signatureLabel = UILabel()
        signatureVCContainer = UIView()

        signOffSignatureContainer.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        signOffSignatureContainer.addSubview(signatureLabel)
        signOffSignatureContainer.addSubview(clearSignatureButton)
        signOffSignatureContainer.addSubview(signatureVCContainer)

        // Signature Label
        signatureLabel.text = "Signature"

        signatureLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        [signatureLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: signOffSignatureContainer.topAnchor, constant: 8),
         signatureLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: signOffSignatureContainer.leadingAnchor, constant: 16)].forEach { $0.isActive = true }

        // Signature Button
        clearSignatureButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(clearSignatureTapped), for: .touchUpInside)
        clearSignatureButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        [clearSignatureButton.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: signOffSignatureContainer.topAnchor, constant: 8),
        clearSignatureButton.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: signatureVCContainer.topAnchor, constant: 8),
        clearSignatureButton.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: signOffSignatureContainer.trailingAnchor, constant: -16)].forEach { $0.isActive = true }

        // Signature Container
        signatureVCContainer.layer.cornerRadius = 2.0
        signatureVCContainer.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.gray.cgColor
        signatureVCContainer.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0.0, height: 0.0)
        signatureVCContainer.layer.shadowRadius = 2.0
        signatureVCContainer.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.5
        signatureVCContainer.layer.borderWidth = 1
        signatureVCContainer.layer.borderColor = UIColor.gray.cgColor
        signatureVCContainer.clipsToBounds = true
        signatureVCContainer.backgroundColor = .white

        signOffSignatureContainer.setContentHuggingPriority(UILayoutPriority(249), for: .vertical)

        signatureVCContainer.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        [signatureVCContainer.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: signatureLabel.bottomAnchor, constant: 8),
            signatureVCContainer.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: signOffSignatureContainer.leadingAnchor, constant: 16),
            signatureVCContainer.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: signOffSignatureContainer.trailingAnchor, constant: -16),
            signatureVCContainer.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 300)].forEach { $0.isActive = true }

        // Signature Controller
        signatureVCContainer.addSubview(signatureViewController.view, stretchToFit: true)

        signatureViewController.didMove(toParent: self)
        signatureViewController.delegate = self
        addChild(signatureViewController)

        [signatureViewController.view.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: signatureVCContainer.topAnchor, constant: 0),
        signatureViewController.view.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: signatureVCContainer.leadingAnchor, constant: 0),
        signatureViewController.view.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: signatureVCContainer.trailingAnchor, constant: 0),
        signatureViewController.view.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: signatureVCContainer.bottomAnchor, constant: 0)].forEach { $0.isActive = true }

        return signOffSignatureContainer
    }()

    lazy var signOffCommentsContainer: UIView = { [unowned self] in
        let signOffCommentsContainer = UIView()

        signOffCommentsTextView = UITextView()
        signOffCommentsLabel = UILabel()

        signOffCommentsContainer.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        signOffCommentsContainer.addSubview(signOffCommentsLabel)
        signOffCommentsContainer.addSubview(signOffCommentsTextView)

        //signOffCommentsContainer.setContentHuggingPriority(UILayoutPriority(249), for: .vertical)

        signOffCommentsLabel.text = "If you have any further sign off comments, please add them here."
        signOffCommentsLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        [signOffCommentsLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: signOffCommentsContainer.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor, constant: 16),
        signOffCommentsLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: signOffCommentsContainer.leadingAnchor, constant: 16),
        signOffCommentsLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: signOffCommentsContainer.trailingAnchor, constant: -16)].forEach { $0.isActive = true }

        signOffCommentsTextView.text = audit.notes
        signOffCommentsTextView.delegate = self
        signOffCommentsTextView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        signOffCommentsTextView.placeholder = "Comments"
        signOffCommentsTextView.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 17.0)
        signOffCommentsTextView.layer.cornerRadius = 2.0
        signOffCommentsTextView.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.gray.cgColor
        signOffCommentsTextView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0.0, height: 0.0)
        signOffCommentsTextView.layer.shadowRadius = 2.0
        signOffCommentsTextView.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.5
        signOffCommentsTextView.layer.borderWidth = 1
        signOffCommentsTextView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.gray.cgColor

        [signOffCommentsTextView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: signOffCommentsLabel.bottomAnchor, constant: 16),
        signOffCommentsTextView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: signOffCommentsContainer.leadingAnchor, constant: 16),
        signOffCommentsTextView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: signOffCommentsContainer.trailingAnchor, constant: -16),
        signOffCommentsTextView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 200)].forEach { $0.isActive = true }

        return signOffCommentsContainer
    }()

    lazy var stackView: UIStackView = {
        let sv = UIStackView(arrangedSubviews: [signOffCommentsContainer, signOffSignatureContainer])
        sv.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        sv.axis = .vertical
        sv.spacing = 16
        sv.distribution = .fill
        sv.alignment = .fill

        return sv
    }()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        setUpView()
    }

    fileprivate func setUpView() {

        view.addSubview(stackView)

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            stackView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor),
            stackView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor),
            stackView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor),
            stackView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor)
        ])

        view.backgroundColor = .white
    }

    // MARK: SignatureDrawingViewControllerDelegate

    func signatureDrawingViewControllerIsEmptyDidChange(controller: SignatureDrawingViewController, isEmpty: Bool) {
        clearSignatureButton.isHidden = isEmpty
    }

    // MARK: Signature Functionality
    private let clearSignatureButton: UIButton = {
        let button = UIButton(type: .custom)
        button.setTitle("[Clear Signature]", for: .normal)
        button.setTitleColor(UIColor.blue, for: .normal)
        button.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
        return button
    }()

    @objc private func clearSignatureTapped() {
        signatureViewController.reset()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `signOffCommentsContainer`, you added Top, Leading, Trailing and Height constraints for the content, but forgot to add a Bottom constraint.

You can get further along by adding this line:

```
signOffCommentsTextView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: signOffCommentsContainer.bottomAnchor, constant: -16)
```

in this block:

```
    [signOffCommentsTextView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: signOffCommentsLabel.bottomAnchor, constant: 16),
     signOffCommentsTextView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: signOffCommentsContainer.leadingAnchor, constant: 16),
     signOffCommentsTextView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: signOffCommentsContainer.trailingAnchor, constant: -16),
     signOffCommentsTextView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 200),

     // add this line
     signOffCommentsTextView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: signOffCommentsContainer.bottomAnchor, constant: -16)

        ].forEach { $0.isActive = true }

    return signOffCommentsContainer
```

A side note...

Your organization of views, subviews and constraints is a bit difficult to follow. I'd suggest grouping code functions, along these lines:

```
    // disable .translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints
    [signOffCommentsContainer, signOffCommentsLabel, signOffCommentsTextView].forEach {
        $0.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    }

    // group constraints logically
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([

        // signOffCommentsLabel Top = 16, Leading = 16, Trailing = -16
        signOffCommentsLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: signOffCommentsContainer.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor, constant: 16),
        signOffCommentsLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: signOffCommentsContainer.leadingAnchor, constant: 16),
        signOffCommentsLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: signOffCommentsContainer.trailingAnchor, constant: -16),

        // signOffCommentsTextView Top = 16, Leading = 16, Trailing = -16
        //  Height = 200, Bottom = -16
        signOffCommentsTextView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: signOffCommentsLabel.bottomAnchor, constant: 16),
        signOffCommentsTextView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: signOffCommentsContainer.leadingAnchor, constant: 16),
        signOffCommentsTextView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: signOffCommentsContainer.trailingAnchor, constant: -16),
        signOffCommentsTextView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 200),
        signOffCommentsTextView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: signOffCommentsContainer.bottomAnchor, constant: -16.0)

    ])
```

I just find it more readable, and easier to follow multi-element constraint relationships this way.

Comment: Thank you for the answer and the suggestion - it makes it much more readable.